# PHP json_encode() making data null

Tags: php, json, jquery

I have this code here:

```
case 'resource_list':
        if(file_exists('content.php')){
            include('../ajax/content.php');
        } else {
            die('does not exist');
        }
        $html = render_content_page($array[1],$array[2]);
        $slate = 'info_slate';
        $reply_array = array(
            'html' => $html,
            'slate' => $slate
        );
        echo json_encode($reply_array);
    break;
```

i have debugged every level right up until `json_encode()` is called. But the data i receive back in my ajax is nul for the html key. This code is essentially a copy and paste of another case the just calls a function other than `render_content_page()` but that works perfectly fine.

$reply_array var_exports to:

```
array (
  'html' => '<ol>
    <li unit="quiz" identifier=""><img src="img/header/notifications.png"/>Fran�ois Vase Volute Krater</li>
    </ol>',
  'slate' => 'info_slate',
)
```

Comment: ^thats helpful, what is it then? and php is just annoying.....

Comment: what php version do you use ?

Comment: Probably the format or contents of `$reply_array`.

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.4, json version 1.2.1

Comment: @FraserK php is not annoying, your decision to not use UTF-8 is coming back to bite you. Next time, use UTF-8 everywhere and you won't have these problems.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My initial thought is that special character in `Fran�ois Vase Volute Krater`, as json_encode only works with UTF-8 encoded data.

Try UTF-8 encoding it before JSON encoding it like so:

```
json_encode(utf8_encode("Fran�ois Vase Volute Krater"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe problem is with encoding?
As manual states, `json_encode()` works only only with utf8 encoded data:

> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.

http://php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](http://php.net/json_encode), `json_encode` expects its input text in UTF-8. Most likely, your input (the `ç`) is not in UTF-8.

Use `utf8_encode` (if you're currently using ISO-8859-1) or [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) (otherwise) to convert input strings to UTF-8.